Question about "ECB mode is OW-CPA secure if block cipher is PRP"
I'm reading "Cryptography Made Simple" Theorem 13.4, which states that "ECB mode is OW-CPA secure assuming the underlying block cipher ek acts like a pseudo-random permutation." I almost understand this theorem, except for one equation:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Pr[A \text{ wins } \mathsf{ECB}[\mathcal{P}]] &= 1 - \Pr[A \text{ does not win } \mathsf{ECB}[\mathcal{P}]] \\
&\le 1 - \frac{l \cdot \binom{N-1}{q}}{\binom{N}{q}}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$
My question is, what $\frac{l \cdot \binom{N-1}{q}}{\binom{N}{q}}$ means?

The notation ${N\choose q}$ is for the number of combinations of $q$ things out of $N$, that is $\frac{N!}{q!(N-q)!}$. Are you asking what the expression $\frac{l\cdot{{N-1}\choose q}}{N\choose q}$ means? What quantity it is intended to represent? or how this expression of that quantity is derived?

I can't derive this equation from $\Pr[{A \text{ does not win } \mathsf{ECB}[\mathcal{P}]}]$

$N=2^n$ is the number of possible block values for the $n$-bit block cipher.
$q_e$ (or $q$ in the question) is the number of chosen plaintext queries that can be made to a block cipher encryption oracle by the algorithm/adversary playing the OW-CPA game.
$\ell$ (or $l$ in the question) is the number of distinct random secret blocks in the ECB plaintext. The algorithm must guess them all to win the game, per the definition figure 11 page 204 in the book (paywalled).
$\binom mk$ (or $^mC_k$ in the book) is $\frac{m!}{k!\cdot(m-k)!}$, the number of choices of $k$ things among $m$.

The proposition discussed in the question, taken from page 257 in the book (paywalled) with minor notation changes, is incorrect. Counterexample: make $N=16=2^4$, $q_e=1$, $\ell=2$, and the proposition becomes $$\Pr[A\text{ wins }\mathsf{ECB}[\mathcal{P}]]\le1-\frac{2\cdot{\binom{15}1}}{\binom{16}1}=-\frac78$$
which is incorrect since a probability can't be negative.
That's somewhat compensated by a later algebra error $$\frac{N-\ell\cdot(N-q_e)}N\le\ell\cdot q_e/N$$
Update: As pointed by in comment by kelalaka, the book's errata (open access) acknowledges some issues

The estimation of winning the ECB game for a PRP is correct, but the proof is wrong. A corrected page is here (open access).

The following applies to both versions of the book's proof.

The book uses an incorrect premise:

for a PRP the adversary cannot learn anything about the output value of the permutation until she queries the permutation on the specific input value

Fact is that when making a query $X$ to a PRP and getting $Y$, we learn that the output for all other inputs $X'\ne X$ is not $Y$, contrary to the quote.

Theorem 13.4 is correct when reduced to

ECB mode is OW-CPA secure assuming the underlying block cipher acts like a pseudo-random permutation.

Note: OW-CPA resistance has limited value in the case of ECB, because it captures the ability of the adversary to decipher the plaintext in it's entirety, when in practice a partial decryption is often a very real threat. Also the quantitative part of the theorem is stated for plaintext with all blocks distinct, which is not insured in practice, and is the basis of the ECB penguin attack.
And I stand unconvinced by the derivation made. Rather than the conventional approach of turning an hypothetical OW-CPA adversary for ECB into an OW-CPA adversary for the block cipher, it's reasoned along the line the best an OW-CPA adversary for ECB can do has at least that probability to fail. This unconventional approach can work. However

The reasoning made to derive that minimal probability of failure

Uses a slightly incorrect argument about PRPs (as discussed above).
Assumes the adversary generates $q_e$ (distinct) plaintexts among $N$ all submitted to the encryption oracle, when a better strategy can make good use of up to $\ell$ further (other distinct) plaintexts not submitted to the encryption oracle.
Asserts without justification the formula $\frac{\ell\cdot\binom{N-1}{q_e}}{\binom Nq}$ (in the question and book) or $\frac{\binom{N-\ell}{q_e}}{\binom Nq}$ (in the revised book page).


From that it's derived (in both versions of the proof's book) $\Pr[A\text{ wins }\mathsf{ECB}[\mathcal{P}]]\le \ell\cdot q_e/N$ which:

Is slightly wrong for $\ell=1$. Proof: consider the algorithm/adversary that makes up to $q_e$ queries with random distinct plaintext blocks, returns the first plaintext block which ciphertext block matches the one challenge ciphertext block if that happens, and otherwise returns yet another random ciphertext block. That yields a probability of winning $\min((q_e+1)/N,1)$, generally slightly above the stated upper bound.
Is extremely loose for large $\ell$. The term $\ell\cdot q_e/N$ in the stated bound grows linearly with $\ell$, when obviously the more blocks to guess the less likely it is to guess them all. Thus we can use $\forall\ell\ge1,\ \Pr[A\text{ wins }\mathsf{ECB}[\mathcal{P}]]\le(q_e+1)/N$ that's already much tighter.




Further update: it can be shown that for a block encryption oracle that's a PRP, any algorithm for the OW-CPA ECB game can be turned into one of at least the same probability of winning for random challenge ciphertext, but which output is limited to using $\min(q_e+\ell,N)$ distinct blocks determined independently of the challenge ciphertext (the first $q_e$ submitted to the oracle, and if necessary some or all of the $\ell$ others used as tentative plaintext blocks for challenge ciphertext blocks that the oracle queries do not produce). That algorithm can succeed only if all the $\ell$ plaintext blocks of the challenger are among the $q_e+\ell$ predetermined values (and then can still fail). With the hypothesis explicitly made by the theorem that the challenger uses distinct plaintext blocks, and $q_e+\ell\le N$, the probability of that can be exactly computed, leadign to the bound.
$$\begin{align}\Pr[A\text{ wins }\mathsf{ECB}[\mathcal{P}]]&\le\prod_{0\le i<\ell}\frac{q_e+\ell-i}{N-i}\\
&\le\left(\frac{q_e+\ell}N\right)^\ell
\end{align}$$
Notes:

If the challenge ciphertext is unrestricted, we obtain the same bound without going thru the first step of this derivation.
This bound decreases exponentially with $\ell$ (assuming $q_e+\ell\le N/2$), rather than increase linearly with $\ell$ for the book's bound.
This bound is reasonably tight when $q_e\gg\ell$, that is a few ECB CPA encryption oracle queries (each essentially equivalent to $\ell$ block encryption queries) are allowed in the standard OW-CPA experiment for ECB.
I'm still struggling at following how the book goes from a bound on the probability of winning the game to the theorem, stated in term of advantage, without considering the probability of winning the game with a random guess.


I think that I need to find new bound of this theorem since the proof has some error.

the errata exist for this p257. Here all of the errata that one needs to print and up inside the book before reading.

@kelalaka: A spot-on link!! I still do not see the argument made as rigorous. It still uses a "the best an adversary against ECB can do has this advantage" methodology. It still states the same incorrect premise for PRPs. And I don't see how $\Pr[{A\text{ wins }\mathsf{ECB}[\mathcal{P}]}]$ could grow with $l$, as stated, given the adversary's goal in OW-CPA as depicted in page 204 figure 11.8: guess the whole plaintext.

Well, AFAIK this book was not liked by the community, your effort requires upvote, though, I cannot judge since no time for deep analysis. The free book is may better suits https://toc.cryptobook.us/

To make things simple they made them complicated, and to have a more complete figure on Page 215. OW doesn't allow Oracle queries, however, in the public key setting, OW-CPA turns into CPA. Maybe they chose OW to indicate the only left side of the A....

Good catch on the errors in the book. One tangent, tho: the criticism of OW-CPA seems to me as an unfair reading of the book... My understanding is that the book simply states a definition without arguing about its meaningfulness. I also don't see anything wrong with the approach of the proof. My reading of it in a game-hopping strategy is that the PRP bound has been accounted for in a previous game hop, and at this point, we just have to establish OW-CPA security, assuming an (information-theoretic) random permutation. That is, a successful ECB distinguisher provides a PRP distinguisher.

With the above, it would be good to establish the correct OW-CPA bounds for an RP. That'd be a nice community contribution. I think it should be possible to derive a nice and "easy" bound using the random systems framework, but I am not proficient with it.

@MarcIlunga: I changed the answer so that my remark about the practical relevance of OW-CPA and the hypothesis about distinct blocks of plaintext in the quantitative part of the theorem is a note, not a criticism of the book. And yes the book's proof sketch can work, only it's not carried correctly for like 3 independent reasons, even after the correction. Plus I admit I miss the end, going from a bound of $\Pr[{A\text{ wins }\mathsf{ECB}[\mathcal{P}]}]$ (that I correct for $\ell=1$ and vastly improve for $\ell>1$) to the theorem stated in term of advantage.

@MarcIlunga: Thinking about it afresh, the book does not "simply states a definition (of OW-CPA) without arguing about its meaningfulness". In theorem 13.4 it explicitly invents a non-standard variant (still noted OW-CPA) where "the challenge ciphertext is $\ell$ distinct blocks in length" (emphasis in the book). I do not see when that variant can be practically relevant. Plus I do not see that this variation is needed in the proof; at least it's not needed for my $(q+1)/N$ bound where the book has $\ell\cdot q/N$.

@fgrieu, I do not dispute that the security notions have much practical usefulness. What I think is unfair is interpreting the introduction of these notions in the book as an endorsement of the practical relevance of these notions. Similarly, Boneh-Shoup introduces the weaker "message recovery" to illustrate reductions. They also prove the semantic security of ECB when restricted to distinct blocks. To me, this is just illustrative information without stating whether it's meaningful in practice. The Made "Simple" book discusses the limitations of "OW" definitions in 11.5.2.
